# How to draw onscreen controls in panda 3d?

Tags: python, panda3d

I want to make a game in panda3d with support for touch because I want it to be playable on my windows tablet also without attaching a keyboard.
What I want to do is, find a way to draw 2d shapes that don't change when the camera is rotated. I want to add a dynamic analog pad so I must be able to animate it when the d-pad is used with mouse/touch.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Make those objects children of `base.render2d`, `base.aspect2d` or `base.pixel2d`. For proper GUI elements take a look at `DirectGUI`, for "I just want to throw these images up on the screen" at `CardMaker`.